I got scam from one pretty girl she told me invest USDT up to 5k and earn daily profit, refer this website, "ogfvs.top" ETH-ERC_20
I got scam from one pretty girl she told me invest USDT up to 5k and earn daily profit, refer this website, "ogfvs.top" ETH-ERC_20 by using this website, and i lost my USDT 4600 recently, they are asking again to deposit money for rewards but its my mistake I trust on blindly, I advise to all boys and girls, please don't trust on anyone regarding the said scams. and don't invest money in online scams
